# Laravel replace collection value based on other collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-collection

Two collections:

```
$users = User::select('id','name')->get();

//outcome  [{"id":"1","name":"John"},{"id":"2","name":"Peter"}]

$orders = Orders::all();

//outcome  [{"id":"1","userid":"1"},{"id":"2","userid":"2"}]
```

How to modify $orders collection "userid" value to replace with real names instead of numeric? I would like to send that to view without modifying database.

Expected outcome of $orders:

```
//outcome  [{"id":"1","userid":"John"},{"id":"2","userid":"Peter"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$orders = Orders::with('user')->get();
```

In Your Order Model:

```
public function user(){
return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'userid');
}
```